# Can we integrate an inequality under specific conditions?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, inequality

While studying inequations I noticed some differences in how equation and inequations are solved.

Among many things we cannot differentiate a inequation like a equation(as a function being greater than other does not imply their slopes have similar relations)

But I thought what if we can under some constraints justify this?

Here is what I tried

For simplicty consider 2 real valued functions of just single variable  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Without loss of generality, let them have relation between them as $$f(x) \geq g(x) \forall x $$

Then if it can be shown that $$f'(x) \geq g'(x)$$ for $c_1 \leq x\leq c_2$ for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ this means that $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x)$ on the required interval. So if we can calculate and show $$f(c_1) \geq g(c_1)$$

Does this mean that $$f(x) \geq g(x)$$ in the required interval? Is this true?

Or to put it formally is the statement $f'(x) \geq g'(x) \implies f(x) \geq g(x)$ true? Why?

Take a simple example

We need to prove $2x+3 \gt x$ for $x\gt 0$ .

Now we take derivative and find $2\gt 1$ which is true for all x. Next we calculate $2(0)+3=3$ and $0$ as values of function. We see that $3\gt 0$ can we now say that we have proved $2x+3 \gt x$ for $x\gt 0$ ?

Comment: I cannot help but wonder if this very elementary and already exists in some textbooks or if there are already are more such operations on inequations in calculus. But I can be completely wrong too.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're after.  Over an interval, $f' > g' \implies f > g$, i.e. integration holds but the reverse (differentiation) does not hold in general.  Which is your question?

Comment: $f(x) = 10+sin(x)$ is always greater than $g(x) = x$ on $x=[0,\pi]$, but $f'(x)=cos(x) \in [-1,1]$ and $g'(x) = 1$.  Without saying more, like a value $x'$ where $f(x') =g(x')$ or a single-crossing condition, you typically cannot prove more about the relationship between the derivatives.

Comment: @Macavity My question is opposite to your implication. "Does differentiation hold under a interval if not why?"

Comment: OK - if so your argument in the post needs correction.  You have been given counter examples already, for e.g. over the interval $[0, 1]$, we have $f=10-x > x = g$, however $f'=-1 < 1 = g'$.  So $f>g$ does not imply $f'> g'$.  When you have counter examples, no further proof is needed.

Comment: @Renard I understand you and yes those two functions cannot be related definitively by diffrentiating them. I want to talk about scenarios where this might be helpful.

Comment: @Macavity I have understood what you say can you explain in a answer why integration holds?  How can we say it is true and neglect constant of integration? I will edit the question a bit.

Comment: As you mentioned already, that's a different question, and we need to talk definite integrals (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities). Why don't you focus on exactly what's troubling you in the examples given and perhaps we can help.

Comment: @Macavity I read that link still I cannot understand why? Can you explain

Comment: OK will explain below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your question on integration, it works a bit like this.  If $h(t) \geqslant 0$ over an interval $[a, b]$, then $\int_a^x h(t) \,dt \geqslant 0$  for any $x \in [a, b]$, this is direct from the definition of the Riemann integral as the limit of a sum of non-negative terms.

Now consider $f(t) \geqslant g(t) $ for all $t \in [a, b]$, then taking $h(t) = f(t)-g(t)$ and following the above logic, it is immediate to conclude $\int_a^x f(t)\, dt \geqslant \int_a^x g(t)\, dt$.  This is why we say we can "integrate" both sides of an inequality.

In your small e.g. for $x> 0$,  $2> 1 \implies \int_0^x2dt > \int_0^x 1dt \implies 2x> x \implies 2x+3 > x$ follows.

Comment: Just one point. One can integrate a strict inequality to get another strict inequality.